# MySQL join, query not ending (loop ?)

Tags: mysql, loops, join

I want to retrieve all the fields in these tables by these joints.
My query runs in a loop and does not stop.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`t_produits`, `t_categories`, `t_sscategories`, `t_produits_couleurs`, `t_couleurs`)
JOIN `t_categories` AS categories ON (`t_produits`.`produits_idcat` = `t_categories`.`categories_id`)
JOIN `t_sscategories` AS sscategories ON (`t_produits`.`produits_idsscat` = `t_sscategories`.`sscategories_id`)
JOIN `t_produits_couleurs` AS produitscouleurs ON (`t_produits`.`produits_idproduit` = `t_produits_couleurs`.`produits_couleurs_idproduit`)
JOIN `t_couleurs` AS couleurs ON (`t_produits_couleurs`.`produits_couleurs_idcouleur` = `t_couleurs`.`couleurs_id`);
```

I've tried this and it worked well :

```
SELECT *
FROM (`t_produits`, `t_categories`)
JOIN `t_categories` AS categories ON (`t_produits`.`produits_idcat` = `t_categories`.`categories_id`)
```

Comment: By runs in a loop do you mean you're executing the query in a loop or that the query doesn't finish executing?

Comment: can someone please edit the "joint" in the question title? :-)

Comment: adding an `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` can help from time to time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have 4 cartesian joins (without a `where` clause the query would join all the tables in `from` clause) and many joins with a given condition. No wonder, the query will never end..

There are two possibilities how you can change query:

**Using a where condition**

```
SELECT *
FROM `t_produits` prod, `t_categories` cat, `t_sscategories` sscat, `t_produits_couleurs` prodcoul, `t_couleurs` coul)
WHERE prod.`produits_idcat` = cat.`categories_id`
  AND prod.`produits_idsscat` = cat.`sscategories_id`
  AND prod.`produits_idproduit` = prodcoul.`produits_couleurs_idproduit`
  AND prodcoul.`produits_couleurs_idcouleur` = coul.`couleurs_id`;
```

**or using joins**:

```
SELECT *
FROM `t_produits` prod
JOIN `t_categories` cat ON prod.`produits_idcat` = cat.`categories_id`
JOIN `t_sscategories` sscat ON prod.`produits_idsscat` = sscat.`sscategories_id`
JOIN `t_produits_couleurs` prodcoul ON prod.`produits_idproduit` = procoul`.`produits_couleurs_idproduit`
JOIN `t_couleurs` coul ON procoul.`produits_couleurs_idcouleur` = coul.`couleurs_id`;
```

One more remark: You don't need to define aliases, if you don't use them

Answer (score 5):

```
FROM (`t_produits`, `t_categories`, `t_sscategories`, `t_produits_couleurs`, `t_couleurs`)
```

Should just look like

```
FROM (`t_produits`)
```

It should speed the query up by a quite big factor...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're mixing two different JOIN styles in one query. Try this

```
SELECT *
  FROM `t_produits` p
  JOIN `t_categories` c ON p.`produits_idcat` = c.`categories_id`
  JOIN `t_sscategories` s ON p.`produits_idsscat` = s.`sscategories_id`
  JOIN `t_produits_couleurs` pc ON p.`produits_idproduit` = pc.`produits_couleurs_idproduit`
  JOIN `t_couleurs` l ON p.`produits_couleurs_idcouleur` = l.`couleurs_id`;
```

*Disclaimer: the query obviously has not been tested*